# Spring exchange file beetwen two REST webservices

Tags: java, spring, web-services, file, rest

I have to send a file from one java class to a Spring rest web service.
USE CASE: From the client, this can select the server, the file on the server and where to save the file. On the server I have to retrieve the file (choice from the client) and send to the client.
At the moment I use a byte array but when the file is over than 50MB I receive heap exception and whereas I us `MultipartFile` from my web page to controller and it works even with file over than 500Mb I though to use the same approach.
From client I use this spring method:

```
Response responseStatus = restTemplate.postForObject(serverIp + "ATS/client/file/?toStorePath={toStorePath}", responseSend, Response.class, toStorePath);
```

and in responseSend I put file name, byte array and other fields that I might delete. I think this is a bad approach because load all the file into heap memory. Is it possible to send a MultipartFile taking the file from file system (or it might show the same problem)?
Or it is possible to transfer in another way (like this [big file transfer](http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-large-sized-files-through-socket/) or [oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1691394?start=15&tstart=0))? But I need to use https

UPDATE possible solution 1:
I thought to the below code, but on the client input stream is null and how can I retrieve the name of file?
Server side:

```
@Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/file",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public javax.ws.rs.core.Response getAcquisition(@RequestParam(value="path", required = true) String path){
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path)){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((len = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        System.out.println("Server size: " + baos.size());
        return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(baos).build();
    }catch(Exception e){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        return null;
    }
```

Client side:

```
@Override
    public Response getFile(String serverIp, String toStorePath, String filePath){
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            String url = serverIp + "ATS/client/file/";
            javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target(url).queryParam("path",filePath).request().get();
            String location = toStorePath + "prova.zip";
            out = new FileOutputStream(location);
            is = (InputStream)response.getEntity();
            int len = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return new Response(false, false,"Your required file has been correctly written!" , null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in FileServicesImpl::getFile :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
            return new Response(false, false,"Error while write file into local file system!" , errorResponse);
        }finally{
            try{
                if (out != null){
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                if (is!=null)is.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
                LOG.error("Threw exception in FileServicesImpl::getFile :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
                return new Response(false, false,"Error during stream closeing!" , errorResponse);
            }
        }
```

this is the exception on the server

> dic 04, 2015 5:00:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ATS] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "client/file", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "client/file", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
>       at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

500mb over REST. I do not like the idea.

Use the webservice to send just a download link to your file and let your http-Server like Apache or [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/) handle the download Request and serve the files.

Comment: I updated with new code, it should avoid the heap error but maybe there is an error in spring configuration. Do you have any idea of the problem?